# When execute Delegator example, I get a "ContractTrapped" error

Tags: substrate, polkadot-js, rust-ink

Build Delegator Contracts...

1. Git clone "https://github.com/paritytech/ink.git".
2. Move "examples/delegator".
3. Build contracts by using "build-all.sh".

Deploy & Execute

1. Excecute Substrate-Node-Template with Contract Pallet.
2. Visit Polkadot/Substrate Portal(https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9944#/accounts)
3. Go to Contract Page(https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9944#/contracts)
4. Deploy "delegator/target/ink/accumulator/accumulator.contract".
5. Deploy "delegator/target/ink/adder/adder.contract" by indicating "accumlator" address as a parameter.
6. Excecute "inc" of adder contract.
7. I get a error "system.ExtrinsicFailed contracts.ContractTrapped"

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could execute delegator example at the latest commit of the github.
I could not recognize this cause of the error,but now the error is solved.

Answer (score 2):

More recently, `ContractTrapped` can be returned if your contract constructor is not `payable`. You currently need to decorate with `payable` as follows:

```
impl Dapp {
    /// Creates a new payable contract
    #[ink(constructor, payable)]
    pub fn new(initial_supply: Balance) -> Self {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: The default Flipper template with `cargo contract new` is actually lacking the `payable` decorator, your comment saved me a lot of debug time

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue when trying to call Smart Contract from within offchain worker test environment.

```
DispatchError::Module { index: 0, error: 17, message: Some("ContractTrapped") }
```

Found here: primitives/sandbox/with_std.rs:275
The error in:

```
Trap(Trap { kind: Unreachable })
```

But still have no idea why it happened and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably late but I will leave this here for future strugglers. If you run into a `TrapCode`, take a closer look at it and what type of `TrapCode` it is. Here is more on `TrapCodes`: https://docs.wasmtime.dev/api/wasmtime/enum.TrapCode.html

I was getting a `TrapCode` for example. My substrate node was telling me that it was a `TrapCode::UnreachableCodeReached` which was because my smart contract did not implement some functions, which other contract were trying to call from the first smart contract, hence unreachable code.

Answer (score 0):

You can run into `ContractTrapped` if your substrate node and [polkadot-js](https://github.com/polkadot-js) versions are not compatible.

Try updating the following in your `packages.json`

```
"@polkadot/api": "<add latest version>",
"@polkadot/api-contract": "<add latest version>",
"@polkadot/types": "<add latest version>",
"@polkadot/util": "<add latest version>"
```

Latest version can be found in the tags on GitHub.

- https://github.com/polkadot-js/api
- https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/tree/master/packages/api-contract
- https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/tree/master/packages/types/src
- https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/tree/master/packages/util/src